# how to pass parameter from npx command to playright.config.js file

Tags: javascript, playwright

i have this axios report in playwright.config.js file
reporter: [['junit', { outputFile: 'results.xml' }],['./aio-reporter.js']],

now I want to pass a parameter to the report when I'm running the test from the command line
ex:
reporter: [['junit', { outputFile: 'results.xml' }],['./aio-reporter.js'], let testcycle],

npx playwright test --testcycle=TC-TY-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option that is simple to implement would be to just use an environment variable in this case to pass in that value. You could run the command like so:

```bash
TESTCYCLE=“TC-TY-2” npx playwright test
```

And then you can reference that value in the code as `process.env.TESTCYCLE`